# How to break poorly implemented One-Time-Pad

Tags: encryption, cryptography, one-time-pad

I have a cipher text, that was created using One-Time-Pad, but the idea is that it was encrypted badly. The message, a section of a book, was encrypted using a pad 256B long repeated many times over (like Vigenere).

Any ideas how to break it or what tools to use?

Comment: "but the idea is that" -- does that mean that this is a homework question? How do you know that it was done badly?

Comment: It's an exercise im looking for resources to learn. The plain text is a fragment of book, pad is uknown.

Comment: While we can help with homework and exercises, we require that you at least try to answer the question and to list what you have already tried.

Comment: I think your answer is here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14343/why-does-a-one-time-pad-key-have-to-be-at-least-as-long-as-a-message

Comment: You need the Kasiski's algorithm to determine the length then, you can use [many time pad](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2249/18298) to find the key. Today, there is an automated work for this (in the above link), however, you may not find an implementation.

Comment: See also [cryptanalysis - Taking advantage of one-time pad key reuse? - Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59/taking-advantage-of-one-time-pad-key-reuse/108#108)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are in possession of many 256-byte strings, that when XOR-ed with the key will result in legible text.

To get started, take the first character of each string. All these have been XORed with the first character of the key. Just try XORing all these characters with all 256 possibilities, and check the output.

How do you now determine which one is the correct answer? For most results, values will be outside ASCII range, and can be discarded. For results that do look like letters, you can check whether the letter occurrence is what you expect (e.g. `e` is the most common letter in English).